# Custom method to Spring Data Repository with Pageable and Page

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I created custom repository and want to create custom native query :

```
public Page<Friend> findFriends(FriendCriteria friendCriteria, Pageable pageable)
```

How can i fit there Pageable object and get results as Page<> object ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar requirement and could not found any direct way of doing it. Here is a code snippet how I have achieved. Hope this will help.

```
public Page<Friend> findFriends(FriendCriteria friendCriteria, Pageable pageable){
   //Find actual content from friendCriteria and call method below.

  extractPage(pageable, <actual content>);

}


public static <T> Page<T> extractPage(Pageable page, List<T> contents) {
        int startIndex = page.getPageNumber() == 0 ? page.getPageNumber() : page.getPageNumber() + page.getPageSize();
        int toIndex = startIndex + page.getPageSize();
        toIndex = toIndex > contents.size() ? contents.size() : toIndex;

        final int total = contents.size();

        List<T> filteredContents;

        if (startIndex < contents.size()) {
            filteredContents = contents.subList(startIndex, toIndex);
        } else {
            filteredContents = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        TotalSupplier totalSupplier = () -> {
            return total;
        };

        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(filteredContents, gotoPage(page.getPageNumber(), page.getPageSize()),
                totalSupplier);
    }

    private static PageRequest gotoPage(int number, int size) {
        return new PageRequest(number, size);
    }
```

Comment: will try this, i get this : The method getPage(List<T>, Pageable, PageableExecutionUtils.TotalSupplier) in the type PageableExecutionUtils is not applicable for the arguments (List<T>, PageRequest, LongSupplier)

Comment: which spring boot version are you using? This code is for 2.0.4.RELEASE.

Comment: 1.5.10.RELEASE version

Comment: Updated my answer. Note: I have not compiled but don't see any reason to fail.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try. One more question, why do i get this error : No property findFriends found for type Friend!. This is custom query method.

Comment: Given detail in question is not enough to answer your question. Can you add repository class and give more detail how are you trying to access?(preferably in new question)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624486/cant-create-custom-query-method-in-spring-data-repository