# Can't create custom query method in Spring Data Repository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I wanted to create custom repository :

```
public interface FriendRepositoryCustom {

    Page<Friend> findFriends(FriendCriteria friendCriteria, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And its implementation :

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class FriendRepositoryCustomImpl implements FriendRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Page<Friend> findFriends(FriendCriteria friendCriteria, Pageable pageable) {
    ...
    }
```

And added it to main repository :

```
@Repository
public interface FriendRepository extends JpaRepository<Friend, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Friend>, FriendRepositoryCustom {

}
```

When i start application i get this error :

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property findFriends found for type Friend!   at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:247)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:378)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:70)
>     ... 43 common frames omitted

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are probably naming your implementation class wrong.

Note that the naming expectations changed with Spring Data 2.0.

For < 2.0 the implementation had to be named as the final repository interface with an additional `Impl` suffix. [See the matching reference documentation for an example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour).

For >= 2.0 the implementation has to be named as the custom interface with an additional `Impl` suffix. [See the current reference documentation for an example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

Note: You don't need any of the `@Repository` annotations.