# Jpa Parameter value element [xxx] did not match expected type [xxx]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Jpa method like below.

```
Set<ApplicationMaterialFile> findAllByProcessInstanceIdAndApplicationMaterialIn(String processInstanceId, Collection<ApplicationMaterial> applicationMaterials);
```

This is the code for call the above Spring Data JPA method. And here will be throw a exception when to call the above Spring Data JPA method.

```
@Override
    public Set<ApplicationMaterialFile> getAllByProcessInstanceIdApplicationMaterialIds(String processInstanceId, Set<Long> applicationMaterialId) {
        List<ApplicationMaterial> applicationMaterials = applicationMaterialService.getAllByIdIfNotExistsThenThrowException(applicationMaterialId);

        return applicationMaterialFileRepository.findAllByProcessInstanceIdAndApplicationMaterialIn(processInstanceId, applicationMaterials);
    }
```

Here is the ApplicationMaterial entity struct.

```
/**
 * 
 * @see <a href="https://code.aliyun.com/butterfly-effect/backend/wikis/plans"
 * @author himly z1399956473@gamil.com
 */
@Table(name = "application_material_library")
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Data
@ToString(exclude = {"university"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"university"})
public class ApplicationMaterial {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String fileFormat;


    private String description;


    private String templateFileUrl;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private University university;


    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Timestamp createdAt;


    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Timestamp updatedAt;
}
```

When to call the Spring Data JPA method `findAllByProcessInstanceIdAndApplicationMaterialIn`  will throw a exception like below

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element
>   [ApplicationMaterial(id=1, name=sdfsf, fileFormat=doc,
>   description=dfsdfds, templateFileUrl=fsdfsdf, createdAt=2018-09-26
>   16:54:09.297, updatedAt=2018-09-26 16:54:23.451)] did not match
>   expected type [com.hikedu.backend.model.ApplicationMaterial (n/a)]

Can someone please help me?

Update:

The table struct:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table application_material_library
(
  id                bigint auto_increment
    primary key,
  created_at        datetime(6)  not null,
  description       varchar(255) null,
  file_format       varchar(255) null,
  name              varchar(255) not null,
  template_file_url varchar(255) null,
  updated_at        datetime(6)  not null,
  university_id     bigint       null,
  constraint FK9kuemh1kjhyt8u16sqw6i6t59
  foreign key (university_id) references universities (id)
);
```

Comment: Is private String fileFormat using in your table?

Comment: yes, it is using in the `application_material_library` table. And the column type is varchar.

Comment: i am not sure if you have any problem about mapping, because we don't see your table field. If you can confirm all mapping is configured correctly and saving new entity is ok or not?

Comment: @huy I was delete the tables and created them again. But it did not work.

Comment: same question, If you can confirm all mapping is configured correctly and saving new entity is ok or not? Because the prerequisite is mapping correct. If you are sure about mapping, then try using @Query on method to define instead of use method name.

Comment: Are you missing university?

Comment: @huy Save new entity is all right. But when call the jpa method still is same error. Ok I will try it.

Comment: @Alien Same error no matter missing or include the university.

Comment: then i suspect the parameters types are mismatching like expecting Long but you are passing int or something like that.

Comment: @Himly please add your table structure.

Comment: @SangamBelose Thank you for  try to help me. I already update my post.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace and format it as code, not as a quote.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data doesn't seem to find your custom method implementation.

Therefore it interprets the method as derived query method and complains that the types of parameters don't match what it expects. The error is strange since it complains, although the types seem to match. But that isn't your problem here. The problem is that the custom method is not found.

[This answer describes how to do a custom implementation depending on which version of Spring Data you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52624752/66686).