# Spring Boot & Data Repositories - fragment implementation x does not implement x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I upgraded from `Spring Boot v.1.5.8 to v.2.1.5`. When I try to start the application I get the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Fragment implementation .OtmUniParentRepository2019GeneratedImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdf9e294 does not implement x.OtmUniParentRepository2019Generated!
```

Why I can't start it anymore?

The files:

> OtoUniChildRepository2019

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "OtoUniChild2019", path = "OtoUniChild2019")
public interface OtoUniChildRepository2019 extends OtoUniChildRepository2019Generated {

}

@Transactional
class OtoUniChildRepository2019Impl extends HeartcoreRepositoryImpl<OtoUniChild> {

    @PostConstruct
    private void setIni() {
        super.setIni(OtoUniChild.TABLENAME, OtoUniChild.getColumnName(), OtoUniChild.class, "AGRIDB2019");
    }

}
```

> OtoUniChildRepository2019Generated

```
public interface OtoUniChildRepository2019Generated extends HeartcoreRepository<OtoUniChild>  {


    OtoUniChild findByIdAndOtoUniParentIsNotNull(@Param("id") String id);

    OtoUniChild findByOtoUniParentId(@Param("id") String id);

}

@Transactional
class OtoUniChildRepository2019GeneratedImpl extends HeartcoreRepositoryImpl<OtoUniChild> {

    @PostConstruct
    private void setIni() {
        super.setIni(OtoUniChild.TABLENAME, OtoUniChild.getColumnName(), OtoUniChild.class, "AGRIDB2019");
    }

}
```

> HeartcoreRepository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface HeartcoreRepository<T extends Heartcore> extends RevisionRepository<T, String, Integer>, PagingAndSortingRepository<T, String>, HeartcoreCustomRepository<T> {

    @Override
    T findOne(String id);

    boolean existsById(String id);

    @Override
    Collection<T> findAll();

    List<T> findAllByKanton(@Param("kanton") String kanton);
}
```

> HeartcoreCustomRepository

```
public interface HeartcoreCustomRepository<T extends Heartcore> {

    List<T> findCustom(String sqlQuery);

    List<T> findCustom(String select, String where);

    Class<T> getType();

    T findOne(String id);

    Collection<T> findAll();

     String getSequence(String sequenceName);
}
```

> HeartcoreCustomRepositoryImpl

```
@Transactional
public class HeartcoreRepositoryImpl<T extends Heartcore> implements HeartcoreCustomRepository<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    // irrelevant code

    public void setIni(String tablename, List<String> columns, Class<T> type, String schema) {
        this.tablename = tablename;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.type = type;
        this.schema = schema;

        MultitenantDataSource multitenantDataSource = (MultitenantDataSource) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().get("hibernate.connection.datasource");
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) multitenantDataSource.determineTargetDataSource();
        try {
            this.dbDriver = dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getDriverName();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// irrelevant code
```

With 1.5.8 it works fine and I couldn't find infos about breaking changes.

EDIT: Is something wrong with this inheritance structure of the repositories? I tried some different approaches but none worked. Is there an other way to implement some basic functionality for repositories?

Comment: Looks like wrong cglib version

Comment: @Jens Do I need to specify it, if we never change it manually?

Comment: The naming conventions for custom implementations changed with 2.0. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52624752/66686